# slick.js animation between slides

Tags: javascript, css, parallax, slick.js, velocity.js

I'm using Slick.js for a hero header in a website. Now I would like to add a parallax effect when we navigate from slide to slide. An example of this can be found here: http://www.boegli.ch/company

Is there a way to override the default css animations and use a library like Velocity.js? or is there an other away to achieve the parallax effect between slides?

I tried to achieve this by using the beforeChange event and then add the animation to my slide. But I get a combination off the default slick.js animation between the slides and my custom animation with velocity.js (the animation below is not the full animation but I see it's not gonne work like this :( )

```
$('#header-hero').slick({
            slidesToShow: 1,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            arrows: false,
            infinite: false,
            dots: false,
            fade: false,
            autoplay: false,
            autoplaySpeed: 5000,       
            speed: 300
        });
$('#header-hero').on('beforeChange', function (event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
parallaxAnimate(this, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide);
});


var parallaxAnimate = function(el, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
        $curr_slide = $(el).find(".header-hero-image[data-slick-index="+currentSlide+"]");
        $next_slide = $(el).find(".header-hero-image[data-slick-index="+nextSlide+"]");

        $curr_slide.velocity({
                translateZ: 0, 
                translateX: "-100%"
            });
}
```

Comment: What have you tried yourself already? To improve on asking questions please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: thx @davejal I added a code sample